# SES: API to get delivery status of mails as json response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I want to get the delivery status of the mails sent through Amazon SES by hitting an API and saving the response in my database. I know of Amazon SNS and sending notification through email, but could not find a solution for this. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no polling mechanism in SES for delivery status.

[The SNS delivery/status notifications that SES provides](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications.html), which you have indicated you are familiar with, is the standard mechanism for this.

Enable these and then subscribe an SQS queue, or a Lambda function, or even an HTTPS endpoint from your app, to the designated SNS topic.  It should be relatively simple using any of these mechanisms to code a solution to store the reports in the database as they are provided to you by SES.